# How to adjust start and end time in Google Apps Script for Google Calendar relative to existing event

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Apps script that takes the calendar events from my personal calendar and adds them to my work calendar as "Busy". This is so that people do not schedule work events when I have personal events (and to keep my personal events private).

I want to adjust the start and end times of the meetings to give me a buffer (similar to how Calendly works).

This is the code that works to create new events:

```
var newEvent = primaryCal.createEvent(primaryEventTitle,evi.getStartTime(),evi.getEndTime());
```

Those functions return dates in the following format `Tue Nov 26 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)`

How can I adjust the `getStartTime()` and `getEndTime()` by -15mins and +15mins so the result of the above is `Tue Nov 26 2019 11:45:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)`.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like I need to convert the time to milliseconds, remove and add the buffer amount, then convert back to a date format.

```
// Number in minutes to add before and after
var buffer = 15;

// Convert start time to milliseconds and subtract buffer
var startTimeInMs = evi.getStartTime().getTime() - (buffer * 60000);

// Convert end time to milliseconds and add the buffer
var endTimeInMs = evi.getEndTime().getTime() + (buffer * 60000);

// Convert start time in milliseconds to new Date
var bufferedStartTime = new Date(startTimeInMs);

// Convert end time in milliseconds to new Date
var bufferedEndTime = new Date(endTimeInMs);

var newEvent = primaryCal.createEvent(primaryEventTitle,bufferedStartTime,bufferedEndTime);
```